# Cmake error when building lammps in linux

Tags: linux, cmake, gpu, lammps

During building lammps using the code

```
cmake -C /home/lammps/cmake/presets/minimal.cmake -D PKG_GPU=on -D GPU_API=cuda -D GPU_PREC=double -D OCL_TUNE=generic -D GPU_ARCH=sm_61 -D CUDPP_OPT=yes -D CUDA_MPS_SUPPORT=yes -D PKG_USER-OMP=on /home/modelling/Desktop/lammps/cmake
loading initial cache file /home/lammps/cmake/presets/minimal.cmake
```

I got that error :

```
CMake Error at Modules/Packages/GPU.cmake:42 (message):
  Must use -DCUDPP_OPT=OFF with -DGPU_CUDA_MPS_SUPPORT=ON
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:537 (include)
```

What should I do?and why?

Comment: "What should I do?" - You should do NOT enable `CUDPP_OPT` option when enable `CUDA_MPS_SUPPORT` one. This is also noted in the documentation: https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Build_extras.html.

Comment: Ik that...I just want to know why? And what each does each option stand for